# Object variable not set

Tags: vba, excel

I keep on getting an "object variable not set" error with this code. I want to offset the startcell cell address to take the average of a corresponding column. However, vba tries to offset the value of the startcell, rather than the cell address. It would be great if someone can offer me some guidance. Thanks!

```
Sub Macro1()

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim rowcount As Integer
    Dim startcell As Range

    startcell = ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 3).Address(False, False)
    rowcount = Range("C2", Range("C2").End(xlDown)).Count

    For i = 1 To rowcount
        If Not Cells(i, 3).Value = Cells(i + 1, 3).Value Then
            startcell.Offset(0, 11).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average( _
            Range(startcell.Offset(0, 8), Cells(i, 11)))
            startcell = ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 1, 3).Address(False, False)
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: use `Set` for the range variable startcell. `Set startcell = ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 3)`

Comment: I did, but now it's giving me an "object required" error?

Comment: use `Set startcell = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(2, 3), Cells(2, 3))`

Comment: [Run-time error '91': Object or With block variable not Set](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vba/8917/vba-run-time-errors/27750/run-time-error-91-object-variable-or-with-block-variable-not-set#t=201701311711197143294)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To save a given range in a variable, you either use its `address`, which is a *string*, or a `Range` *object*. The latter is usually preferred, and it looks like this was you intent.

```
Dim startcell As Range
....
Set startcell = ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 3) ' <-- Set a range object variable
....
Set startcell = ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 1, 3) ' <-- Set
```

On the other hand if you want to use the address (less recommended unless there are specific reasons):

```
Dim startAddr As String ' <--
....
startAddr = ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 3).Address(False, False) ' <-- ok, save address
....
Range(startAddr).Offset(0, 11).Value = ... ' Range(startAddr) reconstructs a range from the address
startAddr = ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 1, 3).Address(False, False)
```